# What purpose does character customization serve in Far Cry 5?

Tags: far-cry-5

In Far Cry 5, players have the ability to customize their characters, pretty early on in the game:

[image: Screenshot of the character customization screen.]

However, I'm not seeing an explicitly defined benefit for doing so. I thought perhaps, since camouflage outfits are available that wearing them *might* help in stealth situations, but I've been unsuccessful in proving this.

[The wiki](https://farcry.fandom.com/wiki/Far_Cry_5_Player_Customization#:%7E:text=5.0%20%2F%201%20May%202018%20update%2C%20the%20player%20was%20given%20the,clothing%20menu%20in%20the%20game.) is also unhelpful, simply describing what can be done in the character customization screen, along with the items that can be unlocked:

> In Far Cry 5 the player can fully customize the player character with various items of clothing, hair styles, and even their gender. The clothing can be obtained through various methods, such as buying outfits in the store, unlocking them through missions, the Ubisoft Club, or by doing Live Events, among others.

This leads me to believe that it's purely cosmetic, but at that point, it's a first person game, so *you* as the player can't see your character. Do your customization choices show in the cutscenes at any point?

---

What purpose does character customization serve in Far Cry 5?

<sub>***Note**: Please use spoiler tags in your answer where appropriate.*</sub>

Comment: Please don't answer in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Character customization has no impact on the game. Neither bright, visible colors, or muted camouflage patterns affect your enemies’ ability to see you.

The only impact that character customization has is for personal freedom and online play. When incapacitated your perspective switches to third person and you can see what clothes your put on. Similarly when playing Far Cry 5 online other players can see how you’ve customized your character.

Lastly, your unlocked clothes can be a sort of milestone to track your progress through the game. Many side missions or optional challenges award clothing on completion, and you can wear them with pride when they’re unlocked

Answer (score -4):

Your friend or a random coop partner can see a fancy skin you paid for.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Unfortunately, this adds nothing to the accepted answer